# How to integrate cloudinary with Meteor 1.3 and AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, meteor, cloudinary

I would like to integrate Cloudinary to my angular-meteor project.
I got the following problems.

I know there is an meteor package lepozepo:cloudinary for implementing cloudinary in meteor, but it do not support angularJS and it seem that the package doesn't provide the method to generate the signature for direct browser upload, or maybe it is not documented.

The official cloudinary_ng seem only have bower package (no npm support).
How can I generate the signature for direct browser upload using Cloudinary node.js package in meteor. It is hard to understand by reading the official documentation and lack of examples.

Anyone could help?

Comment: I do not see any reason why lepozepo:cloudinary could't be used with angular..

Comment: check out my answer, it should be a piece of cake

Answer (score 0):

**lepozepo:cloudinary** can work with angular out of the box

It will not provide the Template helpers, because you are not using blaze, but you can still use the underlying javascript API.

```
Cloudinary._helpers.url(public_id, options)
Cloudinary._helpers.private_url(public_id, options)
Cloudinary._helpers.expiring_url(public_id, options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary doesn't yet officially provide an integration to Meteor.

However, since all of our SDKs are completely open source, and due to our RESTful API you can implement it on your own or just use/imitate the relevant methods from within one of our SDKs (e.g. NodeJS).

For more information on how to generate the signature on your own, and pointers to the relevant piece of code, see: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/203817991-How-to-generate-a-Cloudinary-signature-on-my-own-